# Visual studio spitting out a .lib instead of a .dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, sdk, vst

I tell visual studio to build a .dll but it only builds a .lib no matter what I do.
I have the configuration type set to .dll, the extension is set to .dll, in the pre-processor directives I have "_WINDLL", and I set the output file to be like this "$(CommonProgramW6432)\VST3\Steinberg\$(ProjectName).dll" . However, it still builds a static (.lib) every time and I don't know why. I'm trying to compile a sample program called "AGain" from an sdk called Vst3 which you can get here and try to compile it if you don't mind going through a brutal hellish nightmare just to help me.

here is the warning it gives me after I build the .lib file

```
  Warning   1   warning MSB8012: 
  TargetPath(C:\VST3 SDK\public.sdk\samples\vst\again\win\Win32\Debug\AGain.dll) 
  does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value 
  (C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\VST3\Steinberg\AGain). 
  This may cause your project to build incorrectly. 
  To correct this,   
  please make sure that $(OutDir),
   $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) 
  property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).  
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets 1137
```

This problem appears straight out of the box with no changes done to the source code or project at all.

Answer (score 3):

Go to project properties(alt+enter) then under "Configuration Properties" find the "General" tab. Change "Target Extension" to ".dll". Now, under the "Linker" tab, leave the "Output File" field blank.

Comment: THAT WORKED! thank you so much! I would like to tip you how can I get in touch with you?

Comment: I am confused. I don't see a linker tab anywhere? I am building the same VST example, and I change target to dll, but it still builds a .lib